# VB.NET EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport

I have a .DLL file for x64 architecture without adequate documentation. I tried the following as a .NET Core Console App in Visual Studio 2017 adding the DLL as a reference:

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim newObject As NewNamespace.NewInterface

        'Create New Instance
        newObject = NewNamespace.Factory.Instance.Create()

        'Do something

        'Clean up
        NewNamespace.Factory.Instance.Destroy()

    End Sub
End Module
```

When I tried to run the code in Debug for X64 CPU I get the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException
>
> EntryPointNotFoundException: A library name must be specified in a DllImport attribute applied to non-IJW methods.

EDIT: Removed a lot of unnecessary information

Comment: Try a .NET Framework project instead of .NET Core.

Comment: I still get the same error - System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'GXW3OpenIFManagedFactory' in DLL 'GXW3OpenIF64.dll'.'

Comment: You are successfully adding a reference to that DLL in your Console Application project, right? If so then you definitely should not be using `DllImport` anywhere. Get rid of all that and open the Object Explorer window and see what types and members that indicates are accessible.

Comment: If you're looking inside the DLL and seeing only an interface then it kinda seems like you should have another DLL that contains a class that implements that interface. Is the library publicly available? I've searched for some of the terms from your question and this thread was the only result.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Adding the DLL to the references without DLLImport I get the following error: EntryPointNotFoundException: A library name must be specified in a DllImport attribute applied to non-IJW methods. Is there a way I can solve this without using DLLImport?

Comment: @jmcilhinney it is a DLL which ships with Mitsubishi GX Works 3. I am waiting on their tech support but last time I enquired with their tech support team they denied all knowledge of the Automation API.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - You were right in the first instance. I needed to use my original code without DLLImport in a .NET Framework project. When I tested that I tested it with DLLImport and should have been more thorough. If you make that an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy for you to provide your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same code and references in a .Net Framework Console project in VS2017 build and ran the code without error.